# Check box list event is not firing

Tags: asp.net

I have a drop down list and a checkbox list in a panel.On drop down list selection, check box list will load. While checking check box list item, OnselectedIndexChanged event of checkbox is not firing. Instead of this OnselectedIndexChanged event of drop down list is calling.

please find the below code

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" >             
                    <ContentTemplate>                    
                    <asp:Panel ID="pnldivchkbolst" runat="server" Visible="false">                           


                        <asp:Label ID="lblsupervisor" runat="server" Text="Allocate Supervisor :"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSupervisor" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSupervisor_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        </asp:DropDownList>                  

                        <p>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Selected Students :"></asp:Label>

                            <asp:Label ID="selectitems" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                        </p>

                        <asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="chkstudentlist"  AutoPostBack="true"  
                            OnSelectedIndexChanged="chkstudentlist_SelectedIndexChanged" >
                        </asp:CheckBoxList>             


                        <p>
                            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" CssClass="button1" Text="Submit" OnClick="Submit_SSL_Click" />
                            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnEditSupervisor" CssClass="button1" Visible="false"
                                Text="Edit Supervisor" OnClick="btnEditSupervisor_Click" />

                            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnUnSelect" CssClass="button1" Text="UnSelect"
                                OnClick="btnUnSelect_Click" />
                            <asp:Label ID="lblUnselect" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

                        </p>
                        <tr>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Note: Student Listed in Yellow color have not completed the previous Activity and Students with pink Color are already assinged to   Supervisor"></asp:Label>
                        </tr>
                    </asp:Panel>
                    </ContentTemplate>                   
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In Page_Init method, I have a dynamically created tabcontainer and adding pnldivchkbolst panel inside that tab.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems that you trigger same method for both- add some code

Comment: I don't know what is inside `ddlSupervisor_SelectedIndexChanged` and `chkstudentlist_SelectedIndexChanged`, but your code seems to works just fine.

Comment: In Page_Init method, I have a dynamically created tabcontainer and adding pnldivchkbolst panel inside that tab.

Answer (score 0):

The checkbox list **OnSelectedIndexChanged** property raises the **SelectedIndexChanged** event.  In this event, you would need to interate through the checkboxlist items and check if the selected property has been set to true in order to determine which item was selected.  For example:

```
protected void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChnaged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected == true)
        {
            // this is the one selected by the user
        }
    }
}
```